# Controlling GPIO from website on a separate server

Tags: gpio, python, home-automation, php

I am planning on doing a bit of home automation. I decided on going with the Raspberry Pi, because it is cheap, and can connect to the internet wirelessly via a USB dongle. I was planning on controlling the system through a PHP webpage hosted on my webserver.

I was wondering if I could make it so that when I click a button on the PHP site, it somehow sends a signal to the Raspberry Pi and makes it activate a GPIO pin. I realize that it would be easier to host the webpage on the actual Raspberry Pi itself, but I plan to have multiple Pi's and would like to be able to control all of them with one webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP to create a text or csv file on the server with the instructions needed and then have a python script on the Pi run on a cron schedule that downloads the file and acts on the instructions.

I am currently working on a small project that does just this but just plays a selected mp3 file on the Pi and deletes the file on the server afterwards.

I can provide my code so far if required?

Comment: Seems interesting, about how long does it take from the time you press the button to the time it plays.

Comment: Hi, I currently have a cron task run every 5 mins that FTP's into the server, checks if a file exists if not it exits if it does then it will download the file read the instructions (name, song to play & email address) it then plays the song and sends an email to confirm the song was played and deletes the file so a new one can be created or if not it will just exit the next time cron checks for a file.

So it depends on how close to the 5 minute increments  that the file is created.

Comment: Ah, i see, I would have to do it mush more frequently, like every 10s, which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'd like to see the code if you could please share it?